# Differences between ReplicatedDist and PrivateDist, when to use which

Tags: chapel

How are ReplicatedDist and PrivateDist different? I know the syntax is different ;-) I’ve used PrivateDist extensively in my code and I am wondering what the advantages are of each. Is the ReplicatedDist local access (and known to the compiler) by default? I don’t think the documentation is clear enough.

Comment: **The Primer** says: "...each of the original domain's indices is replicated onto each locale, as are the corresponding array elements. ...  Each locale's copy of the domain or array is known as its *replicand*. Consistency among these ( **`ReplicatedDist`** produced ) array ***replicands*** is NOT maintained automatically; users who want a replicated array to store the same values on every target locale will have to manage that consistency themselves."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How are ReplicatedDist and PrivateDist different?

(A) PrivateDist gives you a single array. ReplicatedDist gives you one array per locale. Normal array accesses give you the array on the current locale. Special methods coming with ReplicatedDist let you access arrays on other locales.

(B) The domain of a PrivateDist array is always the same, `PrivateSpace`. When using ReplicatedDist, you choose the domain that the array on each locale will have.

(C) Performance may differ, for example the amount of communication between locales. Not sure whether one is always better than the other, and if so, which one.

> Is the ReplicatedDist local access (and known to the compiler) by default?

Yes, this is the intention. You may need to wrap the surrounding code in a `local` block for the compiler to take advantage of this.

Comment: As noted above "*I don’t think the documentation is clear enough*" -has Brad received/reserved any new resources in the Chapel Team so as to focus on redesign of the documentation in a move from +/-auto-generated texts (listing constructors) way closer to the new users' view (be it learning or revisiting), where syntax is not the core of the reading experience, where adding both complete examples of use & showing also other aspects of Chapel use-cases in a systematic and user-focused manner will move the Chapel language into a new level? Times might be hard,yet the user-base needs to learn 1st

Comment: Yes, we have a Users Guide. What do you think about contributing to it?

https://chapel-lang.org/docs/users-guide/index.html

Comment: Thanks Vass. Needless to tell me about the state as seen in the last few years. What do I think about contributing? On a professional basis, yes, welcome to discuss terms and conditions and we can make a deal.